# Different Event. Same call but causes System.ArgumentException(Invalid Argument)

Tags: c#, winforms

i receive a sporadic System.ArgumentException(Details: Invalid Argument) in the row

```
    System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(currentBitMap);
```

following method:

```
protected void imageSnapTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
        if (flashFader > 0 && pictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            lock (LockSyncronize)
            {
                System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(currentBitMap);
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(flashFader, 255, 255, 255));
                gr.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, currentBitMap.Width, currentBitMap.Height);
                gr.Dispose();

            }
        }
    ...
    pictureBox.Image = currentBitMap;
...
}
```

imageSnapTimer is a Timer added by the VS UIDesigner. Where imageSnapTimer get triggered by the timer.

```
imageSnapTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(imageSnapTimer_Tick);
```

currentBitMap got changed by a method which is created by

```
videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);

void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    lock (LockSyncronize)
    {
        currentBitMap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
}
```

If i use the same syncronized block imageSnapTimer_Tick in videoSource_NewFrame it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault.

Before I access the currentBitmap I try to save the image.

```
    private void saveScreenShot(Bitmap image)
    {
        image.Save(curPath + "/" + imagesLeft + ".jpg");
        image.Dispose();
        imagesLeft = imagesLeft + 1;
    ...
```

The solution was simply to give a Clone to this method instead to use the original one.

```
    ...
    saveScreenShot((Bitmap)currentBitMap.Clone());
    ...
```